# The values of an enumerated type are static variables of that type. True?

Tags: java, enums

**The values of an enumerated type are static variables of that type.**
Far as i know, the variables are referenced, by the refererence variable but there is no new operator to instantiate an enum object. But is it like how you can initialize an array?

Is this true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the literals of an enum type are `public static final` variables.

Simplified, it looks like this:

```
public final enum FooEnum {
    A, B
}

public final class BarEnum {
    public static final BarEnum A = new BarEnum();
    public static final BarEnum B = new BarEnum();
}
```

In reality, there is a bit more stuff there, such as the list of all enumeration literals, a String identifier (the enum value knows its `name`), an ordinal number and a private Constructor to prevent instantiation (all omitted for clarity of code since question was only about the `static`)

Comment: There is one important difference that your post does not indicate: the constructor of `BarNum` should be private.

Comment: thanks, added as a note since it's pretty important for enums.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik enums are converted to classes and yes the values are static fields in this class: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/enum/enum-converted-to-class/